# How is Git's ‘log filename’ implemented internally

Tags: git

I know that Git doesn’t store data as a series of changesets or deltas, but instead as a series of snapshots. So there isn't a direct relation between the two versions of one file, as shown:

[image: git commits]

When I use the command:

```
git log test.txt
```

How does Git find the 'version 1 and version 2' log in its file system?

In my opinion:

Git will traverse all commit objects (with parent references), then trees etc, to get each log info for the specific file.

But, this does NOT seem very efficient; does Git have some specific algorithm to extract log information or store some extra info to got it?

Comment: Have you considered downloading the git source code and looking?

Comment: The source can be found here: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: What seems inefficient about it?  Compare with, e.g., looking up file `test.txt` in three different directories, `v1/test.txt`, `v2/test.txt`, `v3/test.txt`.

Comment: @torek if I having 1000 commits, but one file only change three times, it is inefficient to traverse 1000 times of log-tree file to got the three snapshots of the file

Comment: True enough.  So, how often do you examine several thousands of commits to determine whether one specific file changed in them?  Is it worth optimizing this particular case?  For that matter, how would you go about optimizing it?  (Note: I'm not saying this is The Answer, I'm saying these are The Questions that should be answered first. :-) )

Comment: +1 for also wondering how git realizes such efficient log traversal.
If traversing all the parent comments is needed, maybe things will slow down if there are massive commits in the repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. For the simplest case (limiting the log output by path name) it works exactly like this:

- Get tree from commit
- Does the path exist in the tree?
- Is the SHA1 of the blob associated with this path different from the previous commit?
  -> **Output it**
- Get next (parent) commit. Repeat.

Answer (score 4):

It's a lot more efficient than you might think.  The actual data for these things gets read in with very few I/Os because of the way git writes packs -- similar-sized things are adjacent, so the history of each tree is very likely to be stored sequentially and compressed extremely well because of the locality.  I/O being lots slower than decompression, that's a win. Then, since the SHA of a tree is the SHA of itself and all its subtrees, git can trivially detect when a subtree is identical to its parents' and take the early-out.  That happens very often since few files tend to change at each commit.

All in all, it's fast enough to not be a problem in practice.